# How to solve null value when using DropDownListFor in View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

There is a problem I have been troubleshooting a day and a half and I need some help.

 The code looks fine , but the issue is that it returns `Null`.

I can get the property of that value on the `View Side`.

 It throws:

> No ViewData IEnumerable.

This is what |I have done so far and I need some help , my `View` use the `Multiple Model` but its correct class name with correct properties.

```
 [HttpPost]
       public ActionResult CourseList() 
        {
            var course = new List<string>() 
            {  "Private(Copyrighted)","Public Domain", "Creative Commons Licences", "CC Attribution", "CC Attribution Share ALike", "CC Attribution Non-Commercial",
              "CC Attribution Non-Commercial Share Alike", "CC Attribution Non Directive", "CC Attribution Non-Commercial No Directives" 
            };
            // List of items here.
            List<SelectListItem> select_list = new List<SelectListItem>();

            var query = from li in course
                        select
                        new SelectListItem
                        {
                            Value = li.ToString(),
                            Text = li.ToString(),
                        };
            select_list = query.ToList();
            ViewBag.course = select_list;
            eNtsaCourseList eCourse = new eNtsaCourseList();

            return View(eCourse);

        }

  // eNtsaRegCourses.
    public class RegCoursesViewModel
    {
        public eNtsaCourses Courses { get; set; }
        public eNtsaCourseList eCourses { get; set; } // I am using this property for my View to access dropdownlist.
        public eNtsaDashboardViewModel Dashboard { get; set; }
        public List<eNtsaCourseList> lsteNtsaDashboard { get; set; }
        public RegCoursesViewModel MainModel { get; set; }

    }
 public class eNtsaCourseList
    {
        public string CourseLicence { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }

        public string Value { get; set; }
        public string CourseList { get; set; }
    }
                     @using (Html.BeginForm("CourseList", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
                                        {
                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                            <label for="Content-Licence" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Content Licence</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-5">
                                                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.eCourses.CourseList, ViewBag.course as List<SelectListItem>)
                                              </div>
                                            </div>

                                        }
```

Comment: I don't have a solution for you, but you're unnecessarily instantiating `select_list` and then setting it to `query.ToList()`. You can just declare it as `List<SelectListItem> select_list;`

Comment: @Audiopolis i have tried that as well, the issue is on View side see it as null. I am debugging the property names now.

Comment: Have you got `ViewBag.course` populated in the `HttpGet` as well, asking because you have shown the `POST` code ?